# Locking on Multithreaded openssl is not working

Tags: c++, multithreading, openssl

I have a server. When I try to run the server with multi threading, it crashes. After that I found, I have to manually provide locking in openssl to avoid crashing. After providing static lock also, server gets crashing. I will attach my code here. can anyone say what's wrong in it?

Code:

```
BIO *bio_err = NULL;
static pthread_mutex_t *lock_cs;
static long *lock_count;
void pthreads_locking_callback(int mode, int type, const char *file,int line)
{
    if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(lock_cs[type]));
        lock_count[type]++;
    } else {
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&(lock_cs[type]));
    }
}
void pthreads_thread_id(CRYPTO_THREADID *tid)
{
    unsigned long data = (unsigned long)pthread_self();
    CRYPTO_THREADID_set_numeric(tid, (unsigned long)data);
}
void thread_setup(void)
{
    int i;
    lock_cs = (pthread_mutex_t*)OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks()*        sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    lock_count = (long int *)OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(long));
    for (i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++) {
        lock_count[i] = 0;
        pthread_mutex_init(&(lock_cs[i]), NULL);
    }
    CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback(pthreads_thread_id);
    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(pthreads_locking_callback);
}
void thread_cleanup(void)
{
    int i;
    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(NULL);
    BIO_printf(bio_err, "cleanup\n");
    for (i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++) {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&(lock_cs[i]));
        BIO_printf(bio_err, "%8ld:%s\n", lock_count[i],   CRYPTO_get_lock_name(i));
    }
    OPENSSL_free(lock_cs);
    OPENSSL_free(lock_count);

    BIO_printf(bio_err, "done cleanup\n");
}
```

Comment: You must provide your server code.

Comment: Is thread_setup() being called just once at the top of main(), and thread_cleanup() being called just once, at the end of main(), after all of the threads have been joined?  If not (e.g. if you are calling thread_setup() and thread_cleanup() as part of each thread's creation and destruction), that would be a problem.

Comment: I called thread_setup before calling creating thread and called thread_cleanup() after pthread_join only.is it correct right?